# jQuery On Click Add Class

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, click, addclass

So I am trying to figure out why this does not work:

https://jsfiddle.net/bv6ort3g/

HTML:

```
<div class="all-btn">All Button</div>

<div class="item all"> item 1 </div>
<div class="item all"> item 2 </div>
<div class="item all"> item 3 </div>
<div class="item all"> item 4 </div>
<div class="item all"> item 5 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.all-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.item {
    display: none;
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.all-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.all').addClass('show');
});
```

Basically I want to click the button which will then add a class of **show** to all the div tags with the class of **all**

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't included jQuery.  Do so under **Frameworks & Extensions**:  https://jsfiddle.net/2e08460L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I've done this...

```
$(function(){
    $(".item").hide();
    $(".all-btn").on("click", function(){
        $(".item").show();
    });
});
```

Or you can use this to toggle between the classes showing and hiding...

```
$(function(){
    $(".item").hide();
    $(".all-btn").on("click", function(){
        $(".item").toggle();
    });
});
```

I've kept your HTML the same...

```
<div class="all-btn">Show Button</div>

<div class="item all">Item 1</div>
<div class="item all">Item 2 </div>
<div class="item all">Item 3 </div>
<div class="item all">Item 4 </div>
<div class="item all">Item 5 </div>
```

However I have removed your `.item` and `.show` and retained your `.all-button` CSS code, but this isn't necessary for this to work.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bv6ort3g/1/

Fancier Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bv6ort3g/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is what I am trying to do but im not so good at JavaScript/jQuery :) https://jsfiddle.net/2e08460L/1/ basically I want to do that but with smooth fading animation simlar to the fadein version but would rather use CSS as the blocks move around I want that to animate also. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Chudz That's not a problem, and your welcome - I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `toggleClass()` method. Considering the css rules you got. Toggle between the two classes

```
 $('.all-btn').on('click', function () {
   $('.all').toggleClass('show item');
 });
```

Or:

```
$('.all-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.all').toggle();
});
```